# fullcalendar refresh events when calendar is initialized inside ajax

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

My way of fetching events for `fullcalendar-v2.0` is slightly different from what I've been through few examples.

```
$.ajax({
   url:url,
   type:'GET',
   success:function(resp){
        var data=resp.data;
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                editable: false,
                eventColor: '#F09A18',
                textColor: 'white',
                lang: 'en-IN',
                timezone:'local',
                eventLimit: 3,
                eventLimitText: 'More',
                weekMode: 'liquid',
                events: $.map(data, function (item, i) {
                    var event = new Object();
                    event.start = moment(new Date(item.fDate*1000)).utc();
                    event.title = item.pName;
                    event.fId = item.id;
                    event.sts=item.sts;
                    return event;
                })
        });
   }
})
```

Now this fetches events properly and renders it. But when I have any update to be done to any of the events, I am not quite getting how I should go with. I went through `refetchEvents` option but then not sure what it will consider as source to fetch events.

So I had to destroy the `fullcalendar` once I update and call the above `ajax` again to refresh the events, which actually scrolls to top and I've to animate and use `scrollTop` to keep the original view. But this I feel is a work around and its not quite good approach. Is there any other way I can just refresh the calendar without performing a `ajax` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I made use of **[`eventClick`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)** option which used to fetch current `event` object and updated event with **[`updateEvent`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/)** method
**Ex**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //other options
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          //update the calEvent
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
    }
});
```

That did the trick for my approach.